# How to use lag() window in a PL/pgsql trigger

Tags: postgresql, function, window

Here are the function and the trigger :

```
create or replace function maj_alti_us_test()
returns trigger 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' as

$BODY$
begin

with altisommet as (
    select altisommet 
    from activite.geo g
    where g.gid = NEW.gidgeo)
    
    select ( case when NEW.proftoit = 0 then (select altisommet from altisommet)
    ELSE lag(NEW.altitoit, 1) OVER() - NEW.proftoit END) 
    into new.altitoit;
            
 return NEW;
END;
$BODY$;

create or replace trigger mytrigger
before insert or update on mytable
for each row execute function maj_alti_us_test()
```

An example to be inserted from a `csv` file:

```
numus   proftoit   profbase ...
1       0          0.35
2       0.35       0.7
3       0.7        2.3
4       2.3        2.8
5       2.8        3.7
```

The function `maj_alti_us_test()` has to fill the field `altitoit` (in mytable) like this:

```
num proftoit altitoit
5   2.80      12.75
4   2.30      15.55
3   0.70      17.85
2   0.35      18.55
1   0.00      18.90
```

num 2: 18.55 = 18.90 - 0.35
num 3: 17.85 = 18.55 - 0.7
...
For now, `alitoit` stays empty but for num 1.

Obviously, this is the wrong way to get the previous `altitoit` value. Do I misuse `lag()` ?

Comment: EDIT: I hope this is better as expected.

Comment: The trigger is defined `for each row`, the CTE looks like it'd result in a single row, which is confirmed by its use in the scalar subquery given to `case` later. In that case the implicit window `over()` which `lag()` operates has only that single row in it. If you want to operate in the context of the full payload of the entire insert statement, you can switch to a [statement-level trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) and do just that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but it does not works as expected either.

Comment: You're welcome to edit the question and add the attempt with a statement-level trigger. Do you always need to operate on the whole incoming batch of records before it reaches the table, or is it ok if you insert them  as they are, with the missing data, and update them afterwards, once they're already in the table? Here's a [recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78085912/5298879) of updating stuff after its inserted, using a window function.

Comment: If you came up with a solution, it would make sense to post a self-answer. If you're still looking for a solution, I could give this a shot if you clarified how you're getting the `18.90`. Is this the sum of all incoming `proftoit` values in the CSV? For example, there's a row with `num` 6 that has `proftoit=12.75` and what you aim to achieve is assign a cumulative/stepping/tumbling/rolling sum to each record, in descending order of their `num`. Table DDL for `activite.geo` and `mytable` would be helpful, too.

Comment: The explanation I have found is that I can't use the `lag()` function on the column where the function is working on. So I have kept the first version of this trigger - which I did not post - which is heavier. Thanks for your attention btw.

Comment: You can't *directly* nest `lag(lag()over())over()`, but you *can* nest them in subqueries and cte's, and also 2nd parameter `lag(val, how_far_back, failover)` can vary how far back it's reaching, which can be expression-based. I recalled this thread because there recently was [a similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78081004/5298879) which then evolved into [another, SQLite one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78171074/5298879), leaving the statement-level trigger idea unexplored because the pg version there was just a test before SQLite, which simply doesn't offer statement-level triggers.

Comment: I believe that here it would be possible to try both a lightweight, index-backed `for each row` trigger *as well as* the statement-level upgrade. I'd simply post an answer, but I'm missing the DDL and where the `18.90` came from (to complete the example of an incoming insert batch).

Comment: `18.90` =(altisommet) comes from the table `geo` called in the `cte` i.e. It is not calculated but just grabs from `geo` when `proftoit = 0`. I hope to answer the question.